# Performing queries to Firebase Real Time Database using Cloud Functions Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm just getting started with Cloud Function as I want to query real time database for multiple parameters but I'm not sure I can achieve what I want.
Basically so far I have my db branched for Country/Region/City so writing rules for it is very tedious.

I then thought of including a `geographic` parameter to my records so I then could denormalize the db.
This would leave me with a problem dough. RTB queries only accepts 1 parameter so to perform queries I should do multiple filtering on the client, 1st to filter the `geographic` parameter then the actual parameter I'm interested in.
I'm already facing this problem when I fetch data on `bookings` node for example where I have `bookingStart` and `bookingEnd` parameters, so to get the record I have make two queries filtering out on the client.

So this new `geographic` would force me to do two queries for any record I need to fetch and three for `bookings`.

Is it possible to use cloud functions instead? Passing in the `geographic` and the query parameter ?

Also the new `geographic` parameter would invalidate the observers I now have on certain nodes (observers are the reason why I chosen RTD over Firestore and branched the db)..but maybe a cloud function could solve this as well.

This is the Json of the actual tree ( Main ), the possible tree using the `geographic` query parameter ( Main2 ), and the possible tree if including `bookingStart` and `bookingEnd` in a `query` parameter ( Main3 ) :

```
"Main" : {
  "Country" : {
    "Italy" : {
      "Region" : {
        "Emila-Romagna" : {
          "City" : {
            "Bologna" : {
              "Workshop Bookings" : {
                "someId" : {
                  "bookingDate" : 1600864644531,
                  "bookingEnd" : 1600853400000,
                  "bookingId" : "someId",
                  "bookingStart" : 1600848000000,
                  "shopName: "someName"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



"Main2" : {
  "WorkShop Bookings" : {
    "someId" : {
      "bookingDate" : 1600864644531,
      "bookingEnd" : 1600853400000,
      "bookingId" : "someId",
      "bookingStart" : 1600848000000,
      "geographical" :"Italy/Emilia-Romagna/Bologna",
      "shopName" : "someName"
      
    }
  }
}

"Main3" : {
  "WorkShop Bookings" : {
    "someId" : {
      "bookingDate" : 1600864644531,
      "bookingEnd" : 1600853400000,
      "bookingId" : "someId",
      "bookingStart" : 1600848000000,
      "query" : "1600848000000/Italy/Emilia-Romagna/Bologna/1600853400000",
      "shopName" : "someName"
      
    }
  }
}
```

What other solutions could be available to solve this two scenarios?
I'm actually thinking of switching to Firestore which has deep queries AND observers..

Many thanks for your help.
Cheers.

Comment: From your explanation, It's not so clear to me how the database would look like with the `geograpfic` parameter and without. Could you please add how  your database would look like in a [JSON tree](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree) format?

Comment: @JoseV Hola Jose Thank you for answering, I now updated the question to include the Json tree and the possible denormalized versions. Also as I now see that realtime observers ara also available for Firestore I'm thinking  of switching db.. This would allow to avoid having to use the `geographic` parameter at all as it can perform deep composite queries, AND to get notified in the client the a New booking document matching Retailers' name gets added to `Workshop Bookings` collection. Seems to fit my needs..